# which is the best API to get all the workitem in TFS?

Tags: api, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to get all the workitem and there child task currently I am using this api.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items

I'm getting all the workitem with there task but not getting all the fields of task.

Comment: Could you get useful information from Cece Dong's answer? Any latest information, feel free to share it here.

Comment: no @JackZhai-MSFT

Comment: @Deepak Jain Do you want to get all the work items or all the fields for a specific work item? what's that mean for `task` you mentioned here? Task work item type?

Comment: yes i want to to get 3 types of worktype Task,Bug and product backlogitem

Comment: Task,bug and product backlogitem are the task type name

Answer (score 2):

Add parameter `$expand=all` in [the api](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#get-a-list-of-work-items). `$expand=all` expands all fields, but it doesn't show the empty fields in response. If you type a value for the field you want to get, you will see it as expected in response.

Please notice, the Rest API URL you use can only get the detailed information of the work item itself, it cannot get the detailed information about the work items that linked to a work item.

You have to use [One-hop Query](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql#a-one-hop-query) to get all the tasks related to a work item and then get the detailed data for each task returned. Refer to this link for details: [Get Work Items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql#get-work-items).

Comment: i am not using API now using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946160/a-list-containing-2-more-lists-works-slow-in-looping-can-i-use-thread-to-make-th?noredirect=1#comment84970276_48946160   could u help me with this !!

Comment: Is it slow when you run query in UI in TFS? You could test with REST api I provided to see whether you have the same behavior.