# A list containing 2 more lists works slow in looping can i use Thread to make this faster?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, tfs, wiql

This is my code in which a list contains 2 more lists where the `WorkItem` collection contains a large number of records such as `7,000 it takes 10 min`. Is there any way to make it faster and in `case` it's deciding the  `workItem` type if it's a bug, task or product backlog item. Please tell me how to make the looping faster. It's taking 10 min to loop 7,000 records can we use `threading` to make it faster?

 have already Tried the parallel.for with lock the workitemlist but getting error."No Sequence found"

```
public void GetProjectInfo(string projectname)
{
    string querystring = string.Format("select [System.Id], [System.Title],[Story.Author],[Story.Owner],[System.AssignedTo]," +
                    " [System.WorkItemType],[Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints],[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority]," +
                    "[Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort], [Actual.Effort.Completed]" +
                    ",[System.State]," +
                        public void GetProjectInfo(string projectname)
                    "[System.IterationPath]" +
                    " FROM WorkItemLinks" +
                    " WHERE" +
                    " ([Source].[System.TeamProject]='{0}'" +
                    " and [Source].[System.WorkitemType] IN ('Feature', 'Bug', 'Product Backlog Item', 'Task')" +
                    ")" + " and ([System.Links.LinkType]='System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward')" +
                    " ORDER BY [System.Id] " +  " mode (Recursive)", projectname);
    GetWorkItemTree(querystring);
}

private void GetWorkItemTree(string query)
{
    var treeQuery = new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Query(_workitemstore, query);
    var links = treeQuery.RunLinkQuery();

    var workItemIds = links.Select(l => l.TargetId).ToArray();

    query = "SELECT * FROM WorkItems";
    var flatQuery = new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Query(_workitemstore, query, workItemIds);
    var workItemCollection1 = flatQuery.RunQuery();

    var workItemList = new List<WorkItemViewModel>();

    for (int i = 0; i < workItemCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        var workItem = workItemCollection[i];

        if (workItem.Type.Name == "Product Backlog Item")
        {
            var model = new WorkItemViewModel()
            {
                FID = (workItem.WorkItemLinks.Count > 0) ? ((workItem.WorkItemLinks[0].LinkTypeEnd.Name.ToString() != "Child") ? workItem.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId : 0) : 0,

                ID = workItem.Id,
                Name = workItem.Title,
                State = workItem.State,

                priorty = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Priority"].Value),
                //   Size =(int) workItem.Fields["Size"].Value ,
                Size = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Effort"].Value),

                StoryPoints = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Story Points"].Value),
                DoneStatus = workItem.Fields["Done Status"].Value.ToString(),
                StoryOwner = workItem.Fields["Story Owner"].Value.ToString(),
                Assignedto = workItem.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),
                StoryAuthor = workItem.Fields["Story Author"].Value.ToString(),
                IterationPath = workItem.IterationPath
            };

            workItemList.Add(model);
        }
        else
        {
            switch (workItem.Type.Name)
            {
                case "Task":
                    var task = new TFSTask()
                    {
                        Storyid = (workItem.WorkItemLinks.Count > 0) ? workItem.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId : 0,
                        ID = workItem.Id,
                        name = workItem.Title,
                        //activity = workItem.Fields["MyCompany.Activity"].Value.ToString(),
                        //start = (DateTime?)workItem.Fields["MyCompany.ActivityStart"].Value,
                        //due = (DateTime?)workItem.Fields["MyCompany.ActivityFinish"].Value,
                        status = workItem.State,
                        IterationPath = workItem.IterationPath,
                        Assignedto = workItem.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),

                        priorty = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Priority"].Value),
                        effort = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["effort"].Value),
                        Completed = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Completed"].Value)

                    };

                    if (task.Storyid != 0)
                    {
                        workItemList.Last().Tasks.Add(task);
                    }
                    break;
                case "Bug":
                    var bug = new TFSIssue()
                    {
                        Storyid = (workItem.WorkItemLinks.Count > 0) ? workItem.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId : 0,
                        ID = workItem.Id,
                        Name = workItem.Title,
                        //start = (DateTime?)workItem.Fields["MyCompany.ActivityStart"].Value,
                        //due = (DateTime?)workItem.Fields["MyCompany.ActivityFinish"].Value,
                        State = workItem.State,
                        IterationPath = workItem.IterationPath,
                        Assignedto = workItem.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),

                        priorty = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Priority"].Value),
                        effort = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["effort"].Value),
                        // Completed = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Completed"].Value)
                    };
                    if (bug.Storyid != 0)
                    {
                        workItemList.Last().Issues.Add(bug);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class WorkItemViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }
    // public DateTime? due { get; set; }
    public int priorty { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    //  public int effort { get; set; }
    public int StoryPoints { get; set; }
    public string DoneStatus { get; set; }
    public string StoryOwner { get; set; }
    public string Assignedto { get; set; }
    public string StoryAuthor { get; set; }
    public string IterationPath { get; set; }
    public int FID { get; set; }
    public List<TFSIssue> Issues { get; set; }
    public List<TFSTask> Tasks { get; set; }

    public WorkItemViewModel()  // Added a public constructor
    {
        Issues = new List<TFSIssue>();
        Tasks = new List<TFSTask>();          
    }
}

public class TFSIssue
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }
    public DateTime? due { get; set; }
    public string IterationPath { get; set; }
    public string Assignedto { get; set; }
    public int priorty { get; set; }
    public int effort { get; set; }
    public int Storyid { get; set; }
    //  public int Completed { get; set; }
}

public class TFSTask
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    //  public string activity { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    //  public DateTime? start { get; set; }
    //  public DateTime? due { get; set; }
    public string IterationPath { get; set; }
    public string Assignedto { get; set; }
    public int priorty { get; set; }
    public int effort { get; set; }
    public int Completed { get; set; }
    public int Storyid { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There is a way to make it faster... use database

Comment: If you really cannot use a database and have to do it in memory, maybe a wise idea is to use another collection, like HashSet

Comment: how to use datatable instead of a list ?

Comment: database, not datatable

Comment: There is no clear reason why 7k items should take 10 min here. 10 milliseconds looks more likely. I don't think you posted the relevant part of your code.

Comment: First, try to find out which code is so slow. One way to do it is to add stopwatches and find out which part of the code is so slow. Or use a profile.

Comment: @HenkHolterman loop is taking 10 min

Comment: loop is slow @Carra

Comment: @Carra i have put stopwatched before and after loop and it shows 10 min

Comment: You are not showing us the complete code.there is no way in memory operations can take 10 minutes even for large collections.I guess somehow you make IO(or network) operations. Are  you using entity framework?Maybe you have lazy loaded properties?Try removing the else(or the If) and see where exactly the time is spent

Comment: it's the full code no entity framework is used

Comment: Show us the type of the workItemCollection class.Is this your class or it’s coming from a library?

Comment: not my class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemcollection(v=vs.120).aspx @GeorgeVovos

Comment: I haven’t used it but from,what you are describing I guess it makes http calls to the server.Does you program work without internet?Can you load all your data in one request?Is it an IEnumerable?can you force it to load(ToArray for example).

Comment: no @GeorgeVovos

Comment: It's slow because `workItem.WorkItemLinks`, when you access it for the first time, makes separate query to get those links to TFS server. So you have 7000 + 1 queries to TFS. So real solution would be to fix your TFS query to either only request only required data, or request everything in one query. However, I don't know TFS so cannot tell how to do that or if that is even possible. Better include your TFS query in question and edit it to make it crystal clear your are querying TFS (now people can only guess that from the tag).

Comment: @Evk have put all the code !!

Comment: The code you've put here would not even compile. You use a variable called "workItemCollection" but it is never defined. I assume you meant "workItemCollection1".

Comment: yes @MineR it's workItemCollection1

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var workItemList = new List<WorkItemViewModel>();

var t = workItemList.select(w => Task.Run(() => {
    // Put the work.
}));

await Task.WhenAll(t);
```

Comment: what abt the Bugs and backlog stories @jose ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
IEnumerable<Data> LoadDataFromDatabase()
{ 
    return ...
}

void ProcessInParallel()
{
   while(true)
   {
      var data = LoadDataFromDatabase().ToList();

      if(!data.Any()) break;

      data.AsParallel().ForEach(ProcessSingleData);
   }
}

void ProcessSingleData(Data d)
{
  // do something with data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the next step is *not* to simply multithread this.

You've got code that's running slow, and you've used a StopWatch object to try to track down where the slowdown's occurring.  Great!  But, you can't stop at the 100-line-long For-Loop.  *Where* in the For loop is the time being spent?  Use the stopwatch to figure out what portion of each loop is being spent on each section, or on each line.  You should be able to say, "This line here is taking 100 milliseconds each time, and over 7000 docs, that's why it's taking 10 minutes."

Right now, you're probably in the position of having either slow code or a slow algorithm/approach to the problem.  You should spend effort fixing *that* first.  *Then* figure out whether multithreading is going to give you good improvements.

Answer (score -2):

It seems you can use threading here,

Maybe Parallel.For can help you.

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: even Put parallel.for with Lock Get error "sequence not found"